# In JavaScript, how do I replace multiple values in a string with replace() function without using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, substring

At work we're using a custom JavaScript engine that has regular expressions disabled for performance reasons.

I've gotten stuck with this problem for the last couple of hours. I simplified it for this post. Let's say I have this string:

```
var str = "nice weather, nice car, nice clothes, nice tv";
```

I want to replace all occurrences of "nice" with "ugly".

JavaScript's `replace()` function does just that - it replaces "nice" with "ugly" but here's the problem - if I do `str.replace("nice", "ugly")` then JavaScript will replace only first occurance of "nice" with "ugly".

I know that the solution to replace all occurrences is to use a regular expression such as `/nice/g` to match globally and run it as `str.replace(/nice/g, "ugly")` but in my case, I can't use a regular expression (because as I mentioned we use a custom JavaScript engine with regular expression engine disabled.)

Bottom line is:
I can't figure out how to replace a string with just `replace()` function. How can I do it?

Comment: I am new to this site, I didn't know I will have only one chance for question :(

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a combination of `.split` and `.join`:

```js
var str = "nice weather, nice car, nice clothes, nice tv";
var newStr = str.split("nice").join("ugly");
console.log(newStr);
```

(PS using a "custom Javascript engine" sounds like a really really bad idea.)